# Bing Maps WP7 Error

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am following this tutorial: http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2010/03/21/Using-the-Silverlight-Bing-Maps-control-on-the-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Task 5 indicates that if I add System.Windows.Browser to the project, it will fix the problem. However, this is not the case and I get the following error:

The primary reference "System.Windows.Browser" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "5.0.5.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "2.0.5.0".

The primary reference "System.Windows.Browser" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" which has a higher version "5.0.5.0" than the version "2.0.5.0" in the current target framework.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That article describes the old way of using Bing Maps on the phone. If you read the update paragraph, it states:

> The Windows Phone 7 RTM tools include a NEW updated Bing Maps Control
>   tailored for the Windows Phone 7.  If you are interested in surfacing
>   maps on the phone use that control.  Step by step instructions are
>   included in the Windows Phone 7 Training Kit located here. The code
>   below still works and if you need to use the full Silverlight control
>   on the Windows Phone 7 RTM, this still works.  However, the Bing Maps
>   control for the Windows Phone 7 is optimized for the phone runtime,
>   gestures and limited resources.

Have you considered using the newer, improved control [from the training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1678) instead?

Comment: Ahah, thank you for pointing that out, Mr Johansson. I'll do that right away.